# React importing function from other file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have recently started a React Project and have been having issues with the following:

Basically, I am trying to build a dialog that pops up right after clicking a button, just like that one:

[image: Dialog Box]

So, I have my Dialog Component which is this one (I use Material-UI's dialog box):

```html
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

export function BuyDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open alert dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Use Google's location service?"}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to
            Google, even when no apps are running.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Disagree
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And I want to launch it on the click of a button :

```
<th><button onClick={BuyDialog}>TEST BUTTON</button></th>
```

As well, I have imported it in my Main Component file:

```
import {BuyDialog} from './Components/BuyDialog';
```

Everytime I click on the button however, I get the typical Invalid hook call error.

Comment: Just remove the test button, and replace it <BuyDialog />

Comment: Do something like this <th><BuyDialog /></th>

Comment: Your code as shown above seems to work fine, https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-playground-dj95b  What version of React are you using?  remember hooks only became official @16.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the dialog component in our application... several of them in fact, many on the same page. You actually render them right in the page... but set the open property using a local state prperty flag that's set to false ... everything else is hooked up as normal. When you want it shown, you change the state of the property tied to the open  property so that it is true... bam! there's your dialog...

I'll see if I can find an example and post it.

Edit - found the example:

```js
<Dialog
// checks to ensure the open prop is defined since the Dialog
// component requires it
    open={props.open === undefined ? false : props.open}
    onClose={props.onClose}
    aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
    aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
>
  <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{title}</DialogTitle>
  <DialogContent>{text}</DialogContent>
  {displayActions()}
</Dialog>
```

We found ourselves using it a lot, so we actually wrapped the Dialog component with our own to simplify development.
displayActions takes are of displaying our Ok/Cancel/Yes/No/etc buttons...

how it is called:

```js
<ConfirmDialog
    title="Submit Test"
    text="This will submit the test for action."
    okcancel
    open={showSubmitDialog}
    onCancel={e => setShowSubmitDialog(false)}
    onOk={onSubmitOk}
/>
```

And last but certainly not least... state management:

```
const [showSubmitDialog, setShowSubmitDialog] = useState(false);
```

Comment: `props.open === undefined ? false : props.open`.  A little tip that can be changed to `Boolean(props.open)`, or just `props.open` if you use defaults.

Comment: @Keith nice, I might go back and refactor that at a later time, I prefer concise, clear code when possible.  I don't think we're using defaults (although we should, I know I know) so I may end up going that route instead anyways.

Answer (score 2):

That is because `BuyDialog` returns a React component. You should use it like `<BuyDialog />` to render the content of the BuyDialog function.

So, it looks like you should replace `<button onClick={BuyDialog}>TEST BUTTON</button>` with `<BuyDialog />`.

`onClick` expects a function that does something.

```js
function doSomething() {
  console.log('Hi!')
}

// This function could be used like
<button onClick={doSomething}>My button</button>
```

Comment: Ok, would it be possible to launch my component in the event handler function?

Comment: Nope. In the event handler you can update some state variable and use that state to show/hide the dialog. But that's exactly what `<BuyDialog />` is doing. So any reason you don't want to just render that component?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this out. This should work.

```html
function Dialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
  };

  const getDialog = () => (<div> Hey Return your dialog from here </div>)

  return (
  <div>
        {!open && <button onClick={handleClickOpen}>Click Me</button>}
        {open && getDialog()}
  </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The event handler should be a function, not a component

Comment: Could you provide some code that proves that this is correct?

Comment: You should place useState in Main component, and pass setOpen in onClick event. For example: <th><button onClick={setOpen(true)}>TEST BUTTON</button></th>